# Bootstrap 3 Togglable Tabs into popover can't working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, popover

I have a question, I want to put tabs into popover , but if tabs in popover , it's can's work, i don't know how to solve this problem , how should i do ? 
please give me some suggestion，thanks.

jquery code

```
$(function(){
    $('.serviceCabin').popover({
        'html': true,
        'content': function () {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
    }); 

});

$(function(){

    $('[data-toggle=tab]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
          if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
            $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass('active');
          }
        });
});
```

html code

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" class="serviceCabin" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" >   

</input>    
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">

        <div role="tabpanel">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#city" data-toggle="tab">city</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#station" data-toggle="tab">station</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#airport" data-toggle="tab">airport</a></li>
               </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="city">
                           <span>city 1</span>         
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane " id="station">                        
                            <span>station 1</span>                          
                    </div>  
                    <div class="tab-pane " id="airport">                        
                            <span>airport 1</span>                          
                    </div>                      
                </div>  
        </div>                                                                                  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `.popover()` method duplicates the `#popover-content` element.

Thus, the `id`'s of all the tabs/tab-panes are duplicated. When toggling between tabs in the popover, you are really just toggling the tabs in the original, hidden `#popover-content` element.

In order to work around this, you could remove the original element that is duplicated.

That would be `$('#popover-content').remove()` in this case.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ddcp1tse/)

```
(function () {
    var tabContent = $('#popover-content').html();    // Cache the HTML
    $('.serviceCabin').popover({
        'html': true,
        'content': function () {
            $('#popover-content').remove();           // Remove the element
            return tabContent;                        // Return the cached HTML
        }
    });
})();
```

---

Alternatively, another solution is to use classes rather than `id`'s for the `.tab-pane` elements.

```
<li><a href=".station" data-toggle="tab">station</a>
```

```
<div class="tab-pane station"><span>station 1</span>
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/myL46v77/)

---

For what it's worth, [this has been brought up a few times on the BS3 github repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4272). It's not a bug.

Comment: Thanks your answer, so if I want to use two or more function in popover, I should remove the original element.